# how to use combox when we have data in json format in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

> ```
> how  to use combox when we have data in json format in react js
> ```

I have a data is in format like [{"value":xxx,"label":"xxxx"},{"value":xxx,"label":"xxxx"}]my

but i need data is expecting like  {['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']}   format.
Can anyone help me im new to react js.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the labels are what you want you can use the map method on javascript arrays

```js
const data = [{"value": 1,"label":"Monday"},{"value":2,"label":"Tuesday"}];

const labels = data.map(i => i.label)

console.log(labels)
```

Just swap i.label for i.value if the text you need is in the value property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function on the existing array,and return a new const like this:

```
 const data = [
    { value: 'Sunday', label: "Sunday" },
    { value: 'Monday', label: "Monday" },
    { value: 'Tuesday', label: "Tuesday" },
    { value: 'Wednesday', label: "Wednesday" },
    { value: 'Thursday', label: "Thursday" },
    { value: 'Friday', label: "Friday" },
    { value: 'Saturday', label: "Saturday" },
  ];

 const days = data.map((day,index)=>{
            return day.label
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a selector component like below

```js
const Dropdown = (props) => {
    const {options, onChange} = props;
    const onChangeHandler = React.useCallback( (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      onChange(e.target.value);
    }, []);
    
    return(
        <select onChange={onChangeHandler}>
        {options.map(o => <option key={o.value} value={o.value}>{o.label}      </option>)}
        </select>
    )
};

  const jsonData = '[{"value":1,"label":"Sunday"},{"value":2,"label":"Monday"},{"value":3,"label":"Tuesday"},{"value":4,"label":"Wednesday"},{"value":5,"label":"Thursday"},{"value":6,"label":"Friday"},{"value":7,"label":"Saturday"}]';
  
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  
const App = (props) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(1);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {<Dropdown options={data} onChange={setSelectedValue} />}
      <div>{selectedValue}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```